# OBS студия. Не корректно воспроизводит звук источник input media видеопотока rtmp. Подскажите как настроить аудио кодек ffmpeg?

Tags: input, аудио, ffmpeg, media, obs

Есть OBS студия ver 30.0.2. Принимает видеопоток rtmp c помощью источника media я так понимаю основанного на ffmpeg. В качестве сервера используется MediaMTX. Звук воспроизводится дрожащим с заиканиями. Подскажите возможно нужно вставить правильные параметры в настройках ffmpeg или в поле формат ввода? Какие параметры для моего случая лучше поставить?
Что интересно, то что VLC воспроизводит поток без искажений звука. Также нормально воспроизводит поток ffplay в командной строке. ffplay выводит такую информацию:

C:\Users\Toliy\YandexDisk\рабочие видео>ffplay "rtmp://IP_stream/live/"
ffplay version 6.0-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2003-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (Rev10, Built by MSYS2 project)
configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-bzlib --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-mediafoundation --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libvpl --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
Input #0, flv, from 'rtmp://IP_stream/live/':0B f=0/0
Duration: N/A, start: 5410.284000, bitrate: N/A
Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30.30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn
Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
5435.68 A-V: -0.021 fd=   1 aq=   23KB vq=  348KB sq=    0B f=0/0

Answer (score 0):

С настройками FFMPEG media источника так и не разобрался. Но нашел другое решение:
Для того чтобы внутренний media источник хорошо воспроизводил звук без заикания, необходимо на ОБС студии где ведется трансляция выбирать аппаратное кодирование потока h264. Проверил на двух устройствах. Для этого на ПК должна быть дискретная видеокарта. Вообще вопрос до конца конечно же не решен, так что буду рад услышать более тонкие настройки ffmpeg встроенного media источника ОБС студии